# Can a druid wear Elven Chain?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, armor

The description of the Elven Chain says that people do not need to be proficient with that armor and they would still reap all the benefits of it.

However, I would think that even though it is magical, it does not change the fact that it is metal and thus the Druid should not be wearing it. Can a druid wear it and get the normal benefit it provides?

Comment: Related, on the consequences of a druid wearing metal armor: [If I multiclass from ranger into Druid, can I still wear metal armor?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69901/if-i-multiclass-from-ranger-into-druid-can-i-still-wear-metal-armor)

Comment: So is your question about whether or not they can wear it or what the side effects would be for a druid that did?

Comment: @PremierBromanov According to Jon's answer, Druids do not really want to wear metal in the first place. Although my question was in regard to what happens to the Druid if he does wear it more than whether he'd want to wear it.

Comment: “Can a druid wear Elven Chain?” is one question, but “What effect does wearing Elven Chain have on a druid?” is a second question. I've removed the second question from this post. If you really did want to ask what *effect* wearing Elven Chain would have on a druid it's a bit late to make this question say that clearly, but you can always post a new question.

Answer (score 17):

It appears that they simply will not wear metal equipment. The PHB says they *will not* use metal equipment. It does not say that they are not proficient with it.

From page 65 of the PHB:

> *Proficiencies*
>
> Armor: Light armor, medium armor, shields **(druids will not wear armor or use shields made of metal)**

Since I can't find any mention of consequences for wearing metal equipment as a druid, and given the wording in the PHB, I can only assume that you have two mutually exclusive options:

1. Be a druid
2. Wear metal equipment

Comment: A druid ceases to be a druid upon donning metal equipment.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Is that still a thing in 5e? Here it simply says they won't (which would leave the question of what happens if they do up to the GM).

Comment: @Jon you left out 3. Be a non druid in non metal armor (for pedantics)

Comment: @Ifusaso If one is a druid and then decides to wear metal armor or shields, that one is no longer a druid. The individual used to be a druid (or never was) but is obviously not one anymore after having worn metal armor or shields. It is unknown to me (according to 5e) what that individual is or has become after such an event happens.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but that's not a unilateral rule; it seems to be up to interpretation. I'm sure many GM's in most situations would run that way, but that doesn't mean you can't allow your player to become the [Iron Druid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Druid_Chronicles) in D&D 5e.

Comment: Some DMs might go for a strong argument rooted in the lore of the game world, to allow it. A ranger who worships Mielikki and then multiclasses to a druid used to be exempt from the metal armor restriction in older editions. A player could make a case for why their specific druid *would*, in fact, wear metal armor.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the same [Sage Advice about Druids and Metal](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-march-2016), a Druid should still get any magical bonuses/abilities from metal armor or shield, if 1) they choose to wear it and 2) the magical ability or item isn't restricted to a class, like Holy Avenger swords are restricted to Paladin class only for their magical abilities.

A good druid just wouldn't want to wear it. But if they did, none of their Druid-ness would be affected anyway.

Comment: Ha! Ha! It looks like the druids explode when wearing metal...