# Can the DM force a Will Save to prevent my character from doing something?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

My character swung Tarzan-style on off a bridge using a rope to try and land on an opposite ledge. He didn't make the skill checks to get to the ledge, but passed the tumble check on the fall and only ended up with some nonlethal damage.

He said I couldn't try again without passing a will save (which I failed).

So I had to roleplay accordingly. Was the DM right in preventing this attempt?

Comment: This is basically asking for opinions.  There's no rule covering this, your GM made a judgement call.  In a certain sense the GM is always right, take his rulings with good grace.  Would folks here have done that, some yes, some no.  Is there a real problem we can solve for you (besides a need for validation)?

Comment: @mxyzplk I get that this an opinion question and less of a rule question, but I was hoping to canvas the collective experience of the people here. Is there a better or more proper venue for this question? I suppose I am just looking for validation. I did put up a little bit of a stink over it, but as always DM has final say.

Comment: I suppose it is related to http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80865/28926

Comment: I guess I don't know how to properly link to another question either. 

Comment: If you are looking for validation, [a forum might be the place to go](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566).

Comment: That link worked just fine! You can make it fancy with a name like `[link words go here](http://example.com)`, but you don't have to and a bare link will be clickable. (Read more by starting a comment and then clicking the **help** link beside the box.)

Comment: Or you can come and discuss it with us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)